# Назначение класса при клике и после отвода мыши от блока. VUE. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Прошу Вас о помощи.
При клике мышью на блок с `<div :class="className" ...>...</div>`, должно происходить следующее:
1. Должно поменяться значение "status", для смены класса блока с .feedBlue на .feedPink, и наоборот.
2. Класс должен сменяться только после покидания курсором этого блока.

```
<template>
<div id="_1" class="card">
    <div :class="className" @click="status = !status" @mouseup="leavel = true" @mouseout="leavel = false">
          <div class="content">
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
    return {status: true, leavel: false}
    },
  computed: {
      className: function() {
        var color;
        var colorBull;
        if (this.status = true) {color = 'feedBlue'} else {color = 'feedPink'};
        if (color == 'feedBlue') {colorBull = 'feedPink'} else {colorBull = 'feedBlue'};

        if (leavel == true) {return colorBull}
          else {return color}
        },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.card {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 509px;
  width: 320px;;
  overflow: hidden;}
.feedBlue, .feedPink {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;}
.feedBlue {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 25px, #1698D9 0) top left;}
.feedPink {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 25px, rgb(255, 0, 140) 0) top left;}
.content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 312px;
  height: 472px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 23px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0) top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю у вас проблема в том, что status изменяется во время клика. Из-за этого перевызывается computed и меняется класс. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы переменная status не была реактивной - т.е не заставляла computed-ы перевызываться. Этого можно добиться следующим образом:

```
data () {
return { leavel: false };
},
created: function() {
  this.status = false;
},
computed: {
  className: function() {
    var color;
    var colorBull;
    if (this.status = true) {color = 'feedBlue'} else {color = 'feedPink'};
    if (color == 'feedBlue') {colorBull = 'feedPink'} else {colorBull = 'feedBlue'};

    if (leavel == true) {return colorBull}
      else {return color}
    },
},
```

Функцию className можно порефакторить, но это уже не касается сути вопроса:)

Comment: Попробовал, created - почему-то делает значение константой и оно не меняется при клике

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Получилось!!!
Только теперь при перемещении мыши по блоку, классы меняются с одного на другой, но нажатие отрабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил не без совета Михаила, он подсказал верное направление,
 если отправляем в created status, соответственно 
следует отправить и leavel, как подобный счетчик, после выполняем первые два блока IF для инвертирования цвета, уверен что можно было 
сделать легче, через функцию - не получилось по непонятным мне 
причинам, часто прогуливал занятия про программированию все таки, и 
все же как умею. Дальше идет массив из IF для выбора соответствующего
 цвета согласно двух параметров.

```
<template>
<div id="_1" class="card">
    <div :class="className">
          <div class="content" @click="status = !status" @mouseout="leavel = !leavel">
            <div class="background">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
    return { leavel: false}
  },
  created: function() {
  this.status = true;
  },
  created: function() {
  this.leavel = false;
  },
  computed: {
    className: function() {
      var color, colorBull
      if (this.status == true) {color = 'feedBlue'} else {color = 'feedPink'}
      if (color = 'feedBlue') {colorBull = 'feedPink'} else {color = 'feedBlue'}
         if ((this.leavel == false) && (this.status == true)) {
            return color
         } else if ((this.leavel == false) && (this.status == false)) {
            return colorBull
         } else if ((this.leavel == true) && (this.status == false)) {
            return colorBull
         } else {return color}
      },      
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Будьте осторожны - у вас у компонента метод created два раза определяется. Второе определение перезатрёт первое и status не будет проинициализирован